# cakephp drop down list?

Tags: php, cakephp

Does CakePHP have a form helper for html drop downs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's an explicit [`FormHelper::select`](http://book.cakephp.org/complete/1383/Form#select-1430) and `array('type' => 'select')` and select fields are automatically created [in certain circumstances](http://book.cakephp.org/complete/1383/Form#Automagic-Form-Elements-1390) for belongsTo relations.

Answer (score 3):

The quick answer is yes:

```
echo $this->Form->input('fieldName2', array('type' => 'select', 'options' => $array_of_options));
```

If you have a helper inclusion already added to the controller, make sure you include the Form helper `var $helper = array('Html', 'Javascript','Form',...);`.

Then in your views you can build forms like this:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('ModelName', array('action' => 'nameOfAction'));
echo $this->Form->input('fieldName');
echo $this->Form->input('fieldName2', array('type' => 'select', 'options' => $array_of_options));
echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit', true));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip to supplement the above (on point) answers: 
the *find('list', $params)* model method can often be very helpful in generating your drop down list arrays.  Check out more information on that here: http://book.cakephp.org/view/449/find#find-list-810